# Sync between two google drive folders

Tags: google-drive

How I can sync two folders in google drive account? I try to copy, Transmit, Forklift but it very slow approach? Maybe exists some script or app for sync two folders in one google drive account.

Comment: I find it a bit unclear what you are asking. Maybe you could edit the question with an example or other means of making it more clear?

Comment: I think they want two folders in one google drive to have identical contents. Not sure though.

Comment: How to do it "in the cloud" i.e. a web application, would be off-topic here as problems are expected to be with your *computer hardware or software* rather than an online account. This is aside from the question simply being "is there a script or app" which is off topic due to being a software/product recommendation request.

Answer (score 1):

I tried [MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com) with very good results when its free tier had a little more generous data quota. Another option may be [Rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/) sync.